# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop even there is a key?

Tags: json, reactjs

Always getting the warning even though i have the key in my component. I already tried just putting "post" still wont work. Is the problem in the code or in the data?

**Container Code**

```
 return(
    <div className="listcontainer">
        {data.map(post => {
            return(
                <> 
                <ListItem 
                key ={post.id}
                gender = {post.gender}
                category ={post.category}
                name = {post.name}
                stock = {post.stock}
                price = {post.price}
                sizes = {post.sizes}
                color = {post.color}
                imgUrl = {post.imgUrl}
                />
                </>
            )
        })
```

**Example of the data**

```
{
            "id": 1,
            "gender":"Male",
            "category":"tshirt",
            "name":"Striped Tee",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 500,
            "sizes":["S", "M", "L"],
            "imgUrl":"/img/men-tshirt/bol0929gy4.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "gender":"Male",
                "category":"tshirt",
                "name":"Graphic Tee",
                "stock": 7,
                "price": 450,
                "sizes":["S", "M", "L"],
                "imgUrl":"/img/men-tshirt/boo0086bu3_f.jpg"
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements *immediately returned* from the `.map` need a `key` prop. For a more minimal example of the problem:

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
const App = () => {
    return ['foo', 'bar'].map(
      text => <><div key={text}>{text}</div></>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
</script>
```

The empty fragments aren't doing anything for you here anyway. Just remove them.

```
    {data.map(post => {
        return(
            <ListItem 
            key={post.id}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only a problem in your code to apply the key. You should apply a key to the root element of the component. Your root element is React fragment of a component, When you applied the key on the ListItem you're facing the warning of React. That's why you should remove the fragment to apply the key on the ListItem.Just remove it `<></>`